# Can I simulate a GCM / APNS client device without using a full emulator?

Tags: android, client, apple-push-notifications, simulate

I have an app that needs to push out notifications to thousands of devices up to a few times per day. I'd like to be able to run tests against my server code without actually sending my users anything.

Is there a library in any language that will let me connect to either APNS or GCM as a client without using a full device emulator? I just want to see the network traffic arrive from the server, I don't need to test the app itself on a large scale.

-- EDIT --

One of my goals is to be able to test sending to devices with different configurations without needing to have actual users meeting that need. For example, I'd like to programmatically create and register X devices in each of the timezones and then be able to send notifications to those transient devices in a test scenario. Since I don't have users in a lot of timezones, being tied to real devices (or having to spin up heavy emulators) for testing is a hindrance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For GCM does the 'dry_run' field in the messsage, (see [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html)) suit your purposes? It allows you to send a message from your client to the GCM server without it going out to the actual phones/devices.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you! I should clarify my use case. I'll edit my question.